How do I update `go` dependencies to the latest that are compatible with go 1.21
Maybe this changed with go 1.21, or maybe I just didn't run into this before.
I have go 1.21 in my go.mod file, but when I run go get -u -t with go 1.21.7, I get a slew of errors like
go: go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/detectors/gcp@v1.31.0 requires go >= 1.22 (running go 1.21.7)

I thought go get -u was supposed to honor the go 1.21 directive and prune the version tree so that this kind of error would not happen, but obviously I am wrong (I or doing something wrong).
Is there a way I can automatically update dependencies while still limiting them to ones compatible with go 1.21?

What's the value of your GOTOOLCHAIN env?

@blackgreen I don't have GOTOOLCHAIN set. go env GOTOOLCHAIN returns auto.

what I understand from the docs is that it shouldn't error out unless the GOTOOLCHAIN env is set to some specific value. With it set to auto I'd expect the go command to upgrade the Go version of the main module, though it's possible that doesn't cover switching major versions. It should be documented somewhere, though

Do you need to run go mod tidy first?

Per https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-go, "The go directive sets the minimum version of Go required to use this module. Before Go 1.21, the directive was advisory only; now it is a mandatory requirement: Go toolchains refuse to use modules declaring newer Go versions." I'm guessing that's why you never ran into this before. But it doesn't seem to say anything about how you can comply with that requirement . . .
